# Setting Commands Suggestion in Telegram using Telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I would like to know how I can create a "command sequence" like the one in the image below, I'm using the TELEGRAF module in nodejs

Imagem

[image: 1]

Can't do this function

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by calling directly telegram api `.setMyCommands`:

```js
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

bot.telegram.setMyCommands([
  {
    command: 'test',
    description: 'Test command',
  },
  {
    command: 'greetings',
    description: 'Greetings command',
  }
]);

bot.command('greetings', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hello!!!')); 

bot.launch();

process.once('SIGINT', () => bot.stop('SIGINT'));
process.once('SIGTERM', () => bot.stop('SIGTERM'));
```

or You can do it using telegram app:

1. Talk to BotFather
2. Send him /setcommands
3. Pick the bot which You want to set command menu.

[image: setting commands]

[image: testing commands]

Comment: Just in case, some might have to use `command` property instead of `name` in the `setMyCommands` argument object, otherwise the API may respond with `HTTP 400`.

Answer (score 2):

Now it's not

```
name: 'test'
```

Right is

```
command: 'test'
```